# Why is the map $ D(f) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(R_{f}) $ continuous?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $ R $ be a commutative ring and $ D(f) = \lbrace \mathfrak{p} \in \text{Spec}(R) \;|\; f \notin \mathfrak{p} \rbrace. $

I am having difficulty showing that $ \psi_{f}: D(f) \rightarrow \text{Spec}(R_{f}) $ is continuous.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do the (distinguished) open sets look like on each? They have the same set of prime ideals, and you'd expect that the open sets are exactly the same, too. Are they?

Comment: I know that $ D(f) $  and $ \text{Spec}(R_{f}) $ are related(isomorphic?) though they are not exactly the same. The basic open subsets of $ \text{Spec}(R_f) $ consist of elements $ \frac{a}{f^{n}} $ where $ a \in \mathfrak{p} $ for some $ \mathfrak{p} $ not containing $ f. $ I think....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\spec}{Spec}$$D(f)$ and $\spec(R_f)$ are (exactly) the same provided you're viewing them both as open subschemes of $\spec(R)$. It is possible to consider $D(f)$ only as an open subset without the additional sheaf structure, in which case $\spec(R_f)$ is a subscheme of $\spec(R)$ whose underlying topological space is $D(f)$.

As sets, $D(f)$ and $\spec(R_f)$ are both the set of prime ideals not containing $f$.

A distinguished open set of $\spec(R_f)$ looks like $$D(g/f^n) = D(g/1) = \{\mathfrak p \in \spec(R_f) : \mathfrak p \not\ni g/1\}$$ for some element $g/f^n \in R_f$.

A distinguished open set of $D(f)$ (in the subspace topology) looks like $$D(g) \cap D(f) = \{\mathfrak p \in D(f) : \mathfrak p \in D(g)\}.$$

All I'm doing is writing down what the (distinguished) open sets are.

Comment: Thank you Trevor. The reason why I have been stuck on this is that I didn't realise that they are the same thing set-theoretically, and I created a disconnect between the prime ideals not containing $ \frac{g}{f^{n}} $ and those not containing $ g. $ I feel silly

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

A basis of open sets in $\operatorname{Spec}R_f$ is the set of $D_{g/1}$. Show that
$$\psi_f^{-1}\bigl(D_{g/1}\bigr)=D_f\cap D_g=D(fg).$$